# запрос к бд в php при помощи post запроса

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста. Второй день бьюсь, никак не победю(( Никак не могу вытащить строки из базы данных. Не пойму, что делаю не так. Строка запроса к бд не выполняется, и после неё строки тоже. Если строку с запросом закомментировать, строки после неё выполняются.
Строка

```
<select size="1" name="region" onchange="javascript:selectCity();"></select>
```

при этом дополняется закрывающимся тегом непонятно как

Код файла php

```
<?php

ini_set(default_charset,"UTF-8");

# include data base
require "mysql.inc.php";

switch ($_POST['action']){


    case "showRegionForInsert":

            echo '<select size="1" name="region" onchange="javascript:selectCity();">';
     $rows = $DB2->select('SELECT * FROM okmx_aaa_regions WHERE id_country=? ORDER BY region ASC' , $_POST['id_country']);

          foreach ($rows as $numRow => $row) {
               echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['region'].'</option>';
           };

              echo '<option value="9999">post пришёл: '.$_POST['id_country'].'</option>';

            echo '</select5464>';
            break;

    case "showCityForInsert":

            echo '<select size="1" name="city">';
            $rows = $DB->select('SELECT * FROM okmx_aaa_cities WHERE id_region=? ORDER BY city ASC', $_POST['id_region']);
            foreach ($rows as $numRow => $row) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['city'].'</option>';
            };
            echo '</select>';
            break;

};

?>
```

Вобщем, нужно мне настроить на сайте выбор регионов, городов из базы данных

Comment: Меня смущает параметр
    id_country=? 
и хотел бы уточнить что за переменные:
     $rows = $DB2->select(
точнее $DB2.  Это же отсюда??
    $DB2 = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name) or die("<p>Невозможно подключиться к СУБД: " . mysql_error() . ". Ошибка произошла в строке " . __LINE__ . "</p>");

Comment: Меня аж флешбекнлуо в начало 2000-х от этого кода. Советую разграничивать логику и представление. Не нужно мешать php с html. По сабжу же, ошибку то саму покажите. И приведите весь код, включая тот, где инициализируется `$DB2`.

Comment: Ошибки выдавал, когда я менял (для поиска ошибки в коде) логин в файле подключения к БД.HTML же, чтоб в цикле выводить вместе с данными из строк. Хотя я может и не понимаю. $DB2... В посте, окуда я черпнул это всё, не было файла-примера подключения к БД, потому я и предположил, что $DB - это переменная подключения к БД. Я не особо шарю в этом, и даже иногда в том, что говорю))

Comment: Я, на самом деле, не совсем понимаю, в чём именно проблема. `$DB2->select` что возвращает? Выведите `$rows` с помощью `print_r($rows)`. Вообще, я вижу у вас там косяк с кавычками. Вы в каком редакторе код пишете?

Comment: копипастом в sublime3 вставляю. Укажите, пожалуйста, где именно заменить кавычки. print_r($rows) не работает, потому что строка запроса не срабатывает, и всё после неё. Может мне по-другому строку запроса написать? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: `d_country=? ORDER BY region ASC''` у вас тут две одинарные кавычки. Должна быть одна. Что забавно, чуть ниже в другом похожем запросе у вас, всё же, одна.

Comment: это я вставил сюда криво. Поправил. Спасибо. Но ошибка не в ней, точно.

Comment: mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] =&gt; 
    [field_count] =&gt; 
    [lengths] =&gt; 
    [num_rows] =&gt; 
    [type] =&gt; 
)

Это выдаёт print_r($rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос (может кто подскажет чего для улучшения кода - добро пожаловать)) ):

```
<?php

ini_set(default_charset,'UTF-8');

# include data base
 require 'mysql.inc.php';


$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name) 
or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 


switch ($_POST['action']){


case "showRegionForInsert":
      echo '<select size="1" name="region" onchange="javascript:selectCity();">'; 
      $cntr = $_POST['id_country'];

      $query = "SELECT * FROM okmx_aaa_regions WHERE id_country=$cntr";

      $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 

      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      print '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['region'].'</option>';
      }

      $result->free(); 

      echo '</select>';
       $link->close();

      break;


    case "showCityForInsert": 

      echo '<select size="1" name="city" >'; 
      $rgn = $_POST['id_region'];

      $query = "SELECT * FROM okmx_aaa_cities WHERE id_region=$rgn";

      $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 

      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      print '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['city'].'</option>';
      }


      $result->free();

      echo '</select>';
      $link->close();

      break;

};

?>
```